# Can anyone tell me why I have this weird spacing in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

[image]

Please, have a look at this jpg file....It is a line I've just typed into my terminal. It has a rather unusual letter spacing. Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `gnome-terminal`.  It seems to be a bit buggy on some proportional fonts.  I'd either switch to a monospace (as someone else suggested), try another proportional font, or switch terminals (if feasible).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try resetting your monospace font (the font used within terminals) to the default to see if it solves the problem.
Launch the Fonts setting from your menu (either Dash or main menu) and make sure *Monospace font* is set to **Ubuntu Mono 13**.

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue....Ubuntu Mon 13 solved the problem (it looks I've recently changed it to Arial).

Comment: Worked for me... thanks!